# "Absoluter Liebling der ist ..."

Tags: pronoun, genitive

Aus einem Spiegel-Artikel, in dem es um Zahlen in China geht:

> Die 6 (liu) wie auch die 9 (jiu) gelten beispielsweise als Glückszahlen. Absoluter Liebling **der** ist jedoch die 8 (ba), die so ähnlich ausgesprochen wird wie die Bezeichnung für baldigen Reichtum.

Ich kann nur raten, dass "der" in diesem Fall "davon", "von ihnen", "von den Chinesen", "der Chinesen" oder so was bedeutet.

Die alternative Möglichkeit ist, dass es einen Fehler gibt und etwas tatsächlich fehlt (d. h., das soll lauten z. B."Absoluter Liebling der Chinesen ist ...").

Ich neige zur ersten Hypothese.

Ist meine Vermutung richtig?
Wenn ja, ist dieser Gebrauch üblich?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hier fehlt eindeutig ein Wort. Naheliegend ist: absoluter Liebling *der Chinesen*, also die Lieblingszahl der Chinesen.

Answer (score 1):

Es sollte "der Chinesen" heissen oder "der" komplett weglassen geht auch.

Wenn "der" weggelassen wird, dann bezieht sich "Absoluter Liebling ist ..." automatisch auf die Chinesen.